# I want to fetch the value from robot framework in jenkins in json format

Tags: json, api, jenkins-plugins, robotframework

I want to fetch the value from jenkins plugins in json format. robot result must be fetched in json format. I want to use those json value in my java script. im not able to fetc[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YiLW5.png)h the value of robort frame work.

Number of test passed failed value in following i want to fetch.

[i used api/json? to link but it only fetching name, url and color of job. how to fetch plugin value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dv97l.png)